# Label em um botão

Tags: android, button

Como adicionar uma label um um botão, como na imagem?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao clicar nesse botão, essa `label` some, só pra avisar que tem algo novo no menu.
como fazer algo parecido?